# LimeSurvey RPC-JSON API using ruby

Tags: ruby, json-rpc, limesurvey

I've been trying to test the Limesurvey API and I was trying to make a simple ruby script for this. I tried the following gems:

- https://github.com/chriskite/jimson
- https://github.com/jjeffus/rpcjson/issues

I followed the examples on the documentation. For rpcjson:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rpcjson'
    bc = RPC::JSON::Client.new 'http://localhost/limesurvey/index.php/admin/remotecontrol', 2
    bc.get_session_key(username: "xxx", password: "xxx")
```

But I get the following error:
JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:1
55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:1
55:in`new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:1
55:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:4
68:in`JSON'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rpcjson-0.0.2/lib/rpcjson.rb:55
:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in`'

Using Jimson:

```
require 'jimson'
client = Jimson::Client.new('http://localhost/limesurvey/index.php/admin/remotecontrol')
client.get_session_key(username: "xxx", password: "xxx")
```

I get:

Jimson::Client::Error::InvalidResponse: Invalid or empty response from server.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jimson-0.10.0/lib/jimson/client
.rb:75:in `process_single_response'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jimson-0.10.0/lib/jimson/client
.rb:33:in`process_call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jimson-0.10.0/lib/jimson/client
.rb:165:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in`'

Has anyone ever tried this? Thanks in advance!